# youtube-dl only extract playlist info

Tags: python, youtube-dl, python-embedding

```
ydl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL()
with ydl:
    r = ydl.extract_info("myplaylist", download=False)  # don't download, much faster

print(r['uploader'],r['title'],r['thumbnail'])
```

code output like this

```
[youtube:playlist] Downloading playlist playlistidhere - add --no-playlist to just download video videoid
[youtube:playlist] playlistidhere: Downloading webpage
[download] Downloading playlist: playlistnamehere
[youtube:playlist] playlist Spotlight On: June Recap: Downloading 39 videos
[download] Downloading video 1 of 39
[youtube] video_id: Downloading webpage
[youtube] video_id: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] video_id: Extracting video information
[download] Downloading video 2 of 39
[youtube] video_id2: Downloading webpage
[youtube] video_id2: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] video_id2: Extracting video information
[download] Downloading video 3 of 39
[youtube] video_id3: Downloading webpage
[youtube] video_id3: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] video_id3: Extracting video information
[download] Downloading video 4 of 39
[download] Downloading video 39 of 39
[youtube] video_id4: Downloading webpage
[youtube] video_id4: Downloading video info webpage
[youtube] video_id4: Extracting video information
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 5, in <module>
KeyError: 'uploader'
```

but i want only youtube playlist info
my question is how can i get playlist's uploader ,thumnail,all videos thumbnails,videos titles,playlist title etc.

Comment: Your `r` is a playlist, not a video, so it doesn't have an `uploader` attribute (your error tells you this). 

You can suppress the unwanted output by passing the `quiet` option as parameter to `YoutubeDL`.

Comment: I found this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44183473/get-video-information-from-a-list-of-playlist-with-youtube-dl Hope this can resolve.

Answer (score 3):

You can import `youtube_dl`，invoke youtube_dl as ydl and set download=False, here is an example

```
download = False 
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': fileName,     // output filename
    'writesubtitles': True,
    'format': 'mp4',
    'writethumbnail': True
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ie_result = ydl.extract_info(url, download)
```

you can use https://github.com/daomanlet/freesea/blob/master/sites/downloader.py

```
import youtube_dl
from freesea import Download
srv = DownloadService()
ie_result = srv.downloadVideo('https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCaO6VoaYJv4kS-TQO_M-N_g','./',False)
print(ie_result)
```

you will see the ie_result only contain information